# Is there a method for displaying an Android PhotoSphere on an iOS device?

Tags: android, ios, ipad, ios6, photosphere

I am creating an iOS app in HTML5 / CSS / Javascript and want to show Android Photosphere's (VR JPEGs) in the browser, specifically on an iPad with iOS 6. I've looked at this excellent work, but it won't run on my iPad.

codebase:
https://github.com/kennydude/photosphere

sample:
http://kennydude.github.com/photosphere/test.html

Any solutions out there? Thanks in advance,
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to require WebGL which is not supported on Mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Just released - https://developers.google.com/panorama/web/

That should do the job. Works fine on my IOS 6 iPhone 4S.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the developers guide mentioned by gdt I created a "tour" and a general photosphere viewer.
You can see and download the examples [here](https://sites.google.com/site/anynamethatisavailable/virtualtourphotosphere)

I have had feedback and it seems to work fine on iPads.
The loading time might be longer than they need to be because I left the photo spheres at 50MP so each is about 7-8MB